# TikZ externalize to png – Package graphics Error: Division by 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-external

I need to externalize my Ti*k*Z pictures to `.png` files and include those into my final document. In fact, I'll generate two documents, one with vector graphics and one with bitmaps. When searching the web for a method to automate the generation of bitmaps, I found this solution that is even documented in the PGF/Ti*k*Z documentation. (Page 618 in the [documentation](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) of version 3.0.1a)

The requirement for this method is a running installation of `ImageMagick`.

```
\tikzset{
    % Defines a custom style which generates BOTH, .pdf and .png export
    % but prefers the .png on inclusion.
    %
    % This style is not pre-defined, you may need to copy-paste and
    % adjust it.
    png export/.style={
        external/system call/.add=
            {}
            {; convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
        %
        /pgf/images/external info,
        /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
            \includegraphics
                [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
                {##1.png}%
        },
    }
}
```

To activate the script automatically to apply this to the whole document, one can add `png export` to the `\tikzset` command.

I did recompile my document, having this code in my preamble and waited for some time, then I was flooded with error messages. This error message occurs for each graph.

> [8] (./img/graphs/foobar.tex
>   ===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "img/build/foobar" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"; convert -density 300 "img/build/foobar.pdf" "img/build/foobar.png"' ========
>   \openout5 = `main.auxlock'.
>
> runsystem(xelatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "img/build/foobar" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"; convert -density 300 "img/build/foobar.pdf" "img/build/foobar.png")...executed.
>
> \openout5 = `main.auxlock'.
>
> LaTeX Warning: File `.png' not found on input line 66.
>
> ./img/graphs/foobar.tex:66: Unable to load picture or PDF file '.png'.
>
> <to be read again>
>
> }
>
> l.66 \end{tikzpicture}
>
> The requested image couldn't be read because it was not a recognized image format.
>
> ./img/graphs/foobar.tex:66: Package graphics Error: Division by 0.

Note that both, the `.png` and the `.pdf`, are generated correctly and are in the `./img/graphs` directory. I also checked the `.dpth` files. These do all include the width and height of the respective image.

Why is LaTeX, or `graphics` complaining about not finding a `.png` image if it's definitely there?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

---

#### M(N)WE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% %%%%%%%%
% Preamble
% %%%%%%%%

% Drawing Packages
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz, pgfplots}

% pgfplots
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% TikZ
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\newcommand\usepng{
    \tikzset{external/force remake} % otherwise will use external pdf if it exists
    \tikzset{
        png export/.style = {
            % First we call ImageMagick
            external/system call/.add = {}{; convert -density 300 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"},
            % Now we force the PNG figure to be used instead of the PDF
            /pgf/images/external info,
            /pgf/images/include external/.code = {%
                \includegraphics
                [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]
                {##1.png}%
            },
        },
        % Activate the script
        png export,
    }
}

% Use bitmap images in this document
\usepng



% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin the document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \tikzsetnextfilename{foobar}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel = {x},
            ylabel = {y},
        ]

            \addplot+[mark=none] coordinates {
                (2,-2.8559703)
                (3,-3.5301677)
                (4,-4.3050655)
                (5,-5.1413136)
                (6,-6.0322865)
                (7,-6.9675052)
                (8,-7.9377747)
            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the `standalone` package?

Comment: Yes! I don't want to export a graph alone. I'm exporting a document containing a number of graphs and plots. And I need a version of that document, where all the graphs and plots are bitmap images and one version containing the original vector files.